# Pre-select the values in a multi-select listbox based on records in query results

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, code-behind, jquery-ui-multiselect

Imagine this table:

```
MatchID UserID  MatchField        MatchValue
7          5    MatchInterests        3
8          5    MatchInterests        7
9          5    MatchInterests       12
10         5    MatchInterests       20
11         5    MatchInterests       26
12         2    MatchInterests        7
13         2    MatchInterests       26
14         4    MatchInterests       26
15         5    MatchStates          12
16         5    MatchStates          11
17         2    MatchStates           1
18         2    MatchStates          17
19         4    MatchStates          10
```

What I want to do is pre-select the MatchValues values in a listbox for User 5 for the field MatchInterests. So the resulting dataset of what I want pre-selected would look like this:

```
MatchID UserID  MatchField        MatchValue
7          5    MatchInterests        3
8          5    MatchInterests        7
9          5    MatchInterests       12
10         5    MatchInterests       20
11         5    MatchInterests       26
```

What's the best way to do this?

What I've tried to do is this:

```
string strSQL2 = "SELECT MatchValue FROM tmpUsermatch WHERE MatchField = 'MatchInterests' AND UserID = '" + (DT2["UserID"].ToString()) + "'";
Interests.SelectionMode = ListSelectionMode.Multiple;
using (var con = new SqlConnection(strCon1))
using (var adapter2 = new SqlDataAdapter(strSQL2, con))
   {
     DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
     adapter2.Fill(dt2);
     foreach (DataRow row in dt2.Rows)
     {
       Interests.SelectedValue = row["MatchValue"].ToString();
     }
   }
```

This works, but only causes the value in the *last* record of the dataset to be selected and I need the value in *every* record to be selected.

**As Requested**: markup of control name Interests.

```
<tr>
   <td style="width:160px">
      <asp:Label ID="Label26" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Interests">Interests:</asp:Label>
   </td>
   <td style="width:300px">
      <div id="UCStyle1">
        <asp:ListBox ID="Interests" SelectionMode="Multiple" runat="server">
        </asp:ListBox>
      </div>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Do share markup of control named `Interests`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are effectively overwriting `SelectedValue` on each iteration of the loop which is why you are only seeing the last one selected.

You need to set the `Selected` property on the items themselves or use the `ListBox.SetSelected()` method. There is an example on the method's [documentation page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.setselected(v=vs.110).aspx).

So, instead of

```
Interests.SelectedValue = row["MatchValue"].ToString();
```

you would have

```
Interests.SetSelected(x, true);
```

where `x` is the index of the list item you want to select. You might need to work out the index by e.g. getting the item based on `row["MatchValue"]` if you don't have the indices available at hand.

Comment: Could you elaborate?  That page didn't help me at all.